# Displaying right-to-left text in Team Explorer

Tags: tfs, client, right-to-left

We've started using TFS at work, and I'm migrating my bugs from the previous issue tracking software to TFS.  All of them are written in Hebrew, a right-to-left language, but mixed with English words.
All the text fields in the TFS client are left-to-right, so I have to manually go and press Ctrl-Right-Shift in all the fields in order to read them properly.

Is there any way to change the default text orientation in TFS client?
I looked into customizing the work item form elements, for example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194963.aspx
but I couldn't find any attribute for changing the text orientation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it there is not a way of changing the text orientation in the work item definition.  I've passed your question along to some guys on the team in Microsoft to see if they know of anything.

Answer (score 1):

is there an answer?  Since then I continued searching for a way to do this, but I couldn't find any.

This is a serious usability issue for me, especially with the titles, which have mixed Hebrew-English.  When displaying the issue titles I have to read "backwards".  When scanning a lot of issues, this is a serious pain.

And I do *not* have the spare time to translate 500+ issues from Hebrew to English.